# Pandas qcut and groupby to see one dataframe's rank to another dataframe deciles

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have two dataframes with same columns:

1. portfolio_df: portfolio of stocks
   [image: portfolio_df]
2. universe_df: universe of stocks

I wanted to add a column 'in-sector decile' where it shows the decile of the return on the stocks in the portfolio_df rank within their respective sectors in the universe_df.

I tried to add to a solution I saw on another question:

```
deciles = pd.qcut(index_decile_calc['R2500G t-0'], 10, labels=False, duplicates='drop', retbins=True)
portfolio_info.loc[:,'deciles'] = np.digitize(portfolio_info['R3mo (t-0)']/100,deciles[1])-1
```

by doing

```
deciles2 = index_decile_calc.groupby('GICS Sector')['R2500G t-0'].transform(pd.qcut, 10, labels=False, duplicates='drop', retbins=True)
```

instead but the variation is no longer a tuple.

Comment: The best option for this question is to place sample dataframes in the form of a table or text strings so that they can be reproduced and show the expected result. This will significantly increase your chances of getting a response.